# My window scrolls just fine, however after scrolling the mouse seems to be disoriented, i cant click buttons as the position of the mouse is weird

Tags: jquery

I made a NUI gui, everything is working except for when I scroll. The buttons are unclickable. It's like the mouse is not where the mouse is.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  cursorX = event.pageX;
  cursorY = event.pageY;
  UpdateCursorPos();
});
```

How can I update the position of the mouse after scrolling?

update::
more code

```
    var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
var cursorX = documentWidth / 2;
var cursorY = documentHeight / 2;

function UpdateCursorPos() {
  $(cursor).css('left', cursorX)
  $(cursor).css('top', cursorY)
}

function Click(x, y) {
  var element = $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));
  element.focus().click();
}
```

all code can be found here https://github.com/IllInuz/carshop/blob/master/carshop.html#L1122

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because it is a list of vehicles players can buy however, if they scroll down, the mouse gets messed up, as in, the display doesn't match where it actually is.

Comment: You should never have to update the users cursor position. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, I meant specifically why are you tracking the mouse position on mousemove instead of retrieving it when a mouse click event actually occurs? Similarly you should never change the position of the user's mouse. That's extremely bad UX.

Comment: Ah sorry! i misunderstood, well it is inside a game, its basically a NUI window.
[link](http://prntscr.com/oe1la6)
If users scroll down, and press purchase or sell the button is not reacting cause its not actually there.